# Desktop system doesn't always hit BIOS

Tags: windows, boot, desktop

I have a desktop system that ran fine for months, but now it doesn't even hit BIOS most of the time.

I've replaced a battery on the motherboard (CR2032) and the power supply, and the behavior hasn't changed.

If I disconnect the box from power for a long time (several hours) and then plug in the system, sometimes I'll make it past BIOS.  One time I made it to the login screen and way able to login.  After a few minutes, the OS froze and I had to hard reboot.  Sometimes the boot sequence will make it as far as a screen that says "hit delete to setup BIOS", but after a few reboots, I wont even hit that screen anymore, and nothing will be rendered out to screen.

additional details: 
the motherboard and video card are older and given to me by a friend.  All of the hardware is out of warranty.

please let me know if there are any details you would like to know.

Comment: If it's still under warranty or subject to a hardware support contract this the time to contact the vendor/manufacturer.

Answer (score 10):

This smells like the "Capacitor plague"

You should look for swollen electrolytic capacitors.
See this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague) for an example view.

If you are lucky you can change some of them and have a working board again for a few month.
If not, buy a new one. This is most of the time cheaper than the labor you will need to figure out the exact defect.

Answer (score 2):

Tried unplugging everything until you're down to just power, monitor & keyboard and see if it's any better? And switch to different power, vid card, monitor & keyboard if still no good? Even the lights & speaker stuff, reset switch included (had a computer that would randomly freeze/black screen, turns out the reset switch was shorting).

And is your wall/house power supply good?

If still bad after all that, then definitely problems with cpu or motherboard.